# First time injection doesn't instantiate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

First time calling, the `authenticated` property is `false`, even the credential is OK. If I login once again with the same credential, it will be OK.

Anyway, I am not sure that my factory below is the right way in angularjs or not. Would you please give me any suggestions?

***Factory:***

```
app.factory('authenticatorService',['$resource', function($resource){
    var authenticator = {};

    authenticator.attempt = function(email, password){
        var current = this;
        $resource("/service/authentication/:id",null,{'update' : { method: 'PUT'}})
            .save({'email' : email,'password': password},
                //success
                function(response){
                    current.authenticated = sessionStorage.authenticated = true;
                    current.userinfo = response.user;
                    current.authenticated = true;
                },
                function(response){
                    current.authenticated = false;
                }
            );
        return  this.authenticated;
    };
    authenticator.logout = function(){
        delete sessionStorage.authenticated;
        this.authenticated = false;
        this.userinfo = null;
        return true;
    };
    authenticator.check = function(){
        if(this.userinfo && this.authenticated){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    return authenticator;

}]);
```

***Controller:***

```
app.controller('authenCtrl',
[
'authenticatorService',
'$scope',
'$sanitize',
'$log',
'$location',
function(alert, authenticator, $scope, $sanitize, $log, $location){

    $scope.login = function(){

        if(authenticator.attempt($sanitize($scope.email) ,$sanitize($scope.password))){
            $location.path('/dashboard');
        }else{
            alert.add("danger","Login fail.");
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this.authenticated` in `authenticator.attempt` will return before the asynchronous call from `$resource` has completed.

You will need to wait for the promise to be resolved before returning from the factory, and before receiving in the controller.

Something like this should hopefully work:

Factory:

```
authenticator.attempt = function(email, password){

  var current = this;

  $resource("/service/authentication/:id", null, {'update' : { method: 'PUT'}})
    .save({'email' : email,'password': password},
      function(response){
          current.authenticated = sessionStorage.authenticated = true;
          current.userinfo = response.user;
          current.authenticated = true;
      },
      function(response){
          current.authenticated = false;
      }
    ).$promise.then(function () {
      return current.authenticated;
    });
};
```

Controller:

```
$scope.login = function() {

  var email = $sanitize($scope.email);
  var password = $sanitize($scope.password);

  authenticator.attempt(email, password).then(function(isAuthenticated) {

    if (isAuthenticated) $location.path('/dashboard');
    else alert.add("danger", "Login fail.");

  });
};
```